# Geopackage sync to onedrive slow

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I am using Geopackage stored in a folder using Onedrive. 
Everytime I want to modify my file in QGIS (3.12), it is freezing and onedrive is notifying errors in synchronisation for the geopackages files (gpkg-shm + gpkg-wal). 
When I use shapefiles, I don't have any problems.

Does anyone faced the same issue or should I modify some parameters in QGIS ?

Comment: Perhaps considerations about Client/Server Applications in https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html apply also to direct use from Onedrive. It might be better to work on local GeoPackage and keep a backup in Onedrive.

Comment: Thanks. I found a trick by reducing the upload speed of synchronisation in Onedrive parameters. The sync problems are still occuring but QGIS is not freezing anymore!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue has been reported by other users.

A solution seems to be implemented, see pull requests:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/37264

Comment: In the meanwhile, you could tell OneDrive to ignore certain filetypes (gpkg-shm + gpkg-wal)